# comparing two SQL tables set cut-set to true and else to false

Tags: mysql, join

for my new project I decided to optimize all kind of inefficient SQL queries I've used on my older projects before importing it. After some hours on a problem that in my opinion seems to be very simple I am at a loss. I've got two different Tables that are holding user-IDs

```
table r     table s
+-----+     +-----+
| user|     | user|
+-----+     +-----+
|  2  |     |  1  |
|  3  |     |  4  |
|  4  |     +-----+
+-----+
```

what I want now is to compare both Tables and setting a true or false flag in another column of the result table which shows me what value of table s is in table r. So what I want is just set the cut-set to true. the result table should look like this

```
     result
+-----+-------+
| user| flag  |
+-----+-------+
|  1  | FALSE |
+-----+-------+
|  4  | TRUE  |
+-----+-------+
```

So the user 4 is the only user that is listed in table r. I already tried some solutions with IF clauses but I'm not pro in SQL but I do my best to get closer to that aim. My idea was this query

```
SELECT
    r.user, 
    IF(r.user = s.user, TRUE, FALSE) AS flag
FROM
    r,
    s
```

I know that it isn't correct at all because the query gives me the following 6 rows.

```
     result
+-----+-------+
| user| flag  |
+-----+-------+
|  2  |   0   |
+-----+-------+
|  2  |   0   |
+-----+-------+
|  3  |   0   |
+-----+-------+
|  3  |   0   |
+-----+-------+
|  4  |   0   |
+-----+-------+
|  4  |   1   |
+-----+-------+
```

so the last row to each user seems to be the result I want but the problem is that the false table is combined with the flag and each user has two flags. I don't understand whats going wrong and I would be appreciated if someone could explain me how the SQL server understands my query and what I have to change to get the correct result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have no join condition, so your query is simply creating a cartesian product between the two tables. It then reports true or false depending on whether the users match in a particular pairing. You would see this if you included `s.user` in your SELECT clause.

To do what you want, you should use an outer join.

```
SELECT s.user, r.user IS NOT NULL AS flag
FROM s
LEFT JOIN r
ON r.user = s.user
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT r.user FROM r,s flag WHERE r.user = s.user
```